# How can I allow a class to be declared to use either floats or doubles?

Tags: c#, types

Sorry if the title is poorly worded.  Let's say I have a ray tracer and I want there to be the ability to use either floats or doubles.  How can I make it possible to declare a new instance of the class choosing either floats or doubles?  I don't want to create two classes and call one double and the other single.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not a clean way to handle this in .NET.  Generics do not support arithmetic operations directly.  You can solve this via workarounds such as [MiscUtils](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html) or via the [creation of a separate calculator class and delegating the math to it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33617/Arithmetic-in-Generic-Classes-in-C), but this often makes the code more complex than having two implementations.

You could use `dynamic` here internally, which would work as well.  However, this will add a (slight) overhead, which may mitigate the usefulness of this.  If performance is the main reason you don't want to only support double-precision math, then using dynamic is probably not an option.

One option would be to use [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to create a template that builds both versions of the code from a single source file.  This would provide you full, native support without overhead (it's essentially just writing the two classes for you).

Comment: Bah I write up a whole example using dynamic and your answer blows mine out of the water :(. +1 for you, you win this round.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# generics for this:

```
using System;

class Test<T>
{
    T _value;

    public Test(T t)
    {
    // The field has the same type as the parameter.
    this._value = t;
    }

    public void Write()
    {
    Console.WriteLine(this._value);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Use the generic type Test with an int type parameter.
    Test<int> test1 = new Test<int>(5);
    // Call the Write method.
    test1.Write();

    // Use the generic type Test with a string type parameter.
    Test<string> test2 = new Test<string>("cat");
    test2.Write();
    }
}
```

This blog describes it in a bit more detail for you http://www.dotnetperls.com/generic

Comment: While this works, you can't do much with it, as generics don't support full arithmetic support.

Comment: @ReedCopsey That's exactly why I wish all of the number objects in .NET implemented an interface that has all of the mathmatical operations on it.

Comment: Will this help? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33617/Arithmetic-in-Generic-Classes-in-C

Comment: @GracelessROB Yes, but it's adding a HUGE amount of complexity.  The calculator approach makes your code very difficult to write and maintain.

Comment: Yeh definitely.. i'd agree that 2 classes is a good way to go. I like your idea about using T4 as well.